# How to spawn characters in certain area like a spawn point instead of inside circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm working on a 2D game and i want to make characters spawn from the door to enter the store the script i have keeps spawning them in circle unit which is not what i want. i want them to spawn from the door then i will assign movements to them to walk around the store later. what should i do to achieve spawning them inside a area that i want like shown in this picture.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float spawnRadius = 7, time = 1.5f;

    public GameObject[] enemies;




    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnAnEnemy());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnAnEnemy()
    {
        Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.Find("Bengal").transform.position;
        spawnPos += Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * spawnRadius;

        Instantiate(enemies[Random.Range(0, enemies.Length)], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        StartCoroutine(SpawnAnEnemy());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just spawn the characters at a specific point, you should be able to just remove the `spawnPos += Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * spawnRadius;`  line from the `SpawnAnEnemy` IEnumerator.

To spawn them randomly inside a rectangular area, I would use the `Random.Range` method instead of the unit circle. For example:

```cs
IEnumerator SpawnAnEnemy() {
    Vector2 spawnPos = GameObject.Find("Bengal").transform.position;

    Vector2 pointInRect = new Vector2(
        Random.Range(0, rectWidth),
        Random.Range(0, rectHeight)
        );
    spawnPos += pointInRect;
    ...
}
```

Comment: assuming the usual and the `transform.position` is not he bottom left corner but rather the center of the target rect then probably rather `var pointInRect = new Vector2((Random.value - 0.5f) * rectWidth, (Random.value - 0.5f) * rectHeight));`

Answer (score 1):

remove `spawnPos += Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * spawnRadius;` from the IEnumerator. and if you want to move them around the area of the rectangle, just use

Create empty gameObject name it GameManager then assign this script to it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    public Vector2 moveVector;

}
```

then assign ConstantMove to your characters. like this example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterConstantMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameManager Game_Manager;

    void Start()
    {

        GameObject gameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController");
        Game_Manager = gameController.GetComponent<GameManager>();

    }


    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(Game_Manager.moveVector * Game_Manager.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
    }
}
```